# How to regex Capital Letter without space before | Python 3

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to find specific text within a web page.
My pattern looks something similar like this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9 ,.:;]+)
```

How do I find text before a capital letter without a space before?
For example, from:

```
test Test
```

the following should be found: `test Test`

Where from:

```
testTest
```

the following should be found: `test`
Anyone an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance and cheers,
Dominik

Comment: `find a capital letter without a space before` ..... `testT
Shouldn't be found` .... you just contradicted yourself.

Comment: @cOLDsPEED Sorry, I just edited, please read again.

Comment: Have you tried requiring a space before a capital letter?

Comment: How do I do that without knowing when the space+Capital letter is going to occur? There is an undefined number of other characters before it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this(https://regex101.com/r/GIEtVg/1):

```
[a-z]+?(?=[A-Z])|[a-z]*?\s[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Probably not the best solution but it works